# SFDX uninstallation/update issue

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, mac-os-x

All of a sudden SFDX has stopped working in my MAC laptop. I am unable to retrieve or deploy code. Hence I thought of updating sfdx using the command `sfdx update` which gave the below error.

```
 /Users/starhunter/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx: line 16: 13766 Killed: 9               SFDX_BINPATH="$DIR/sfdx" SFDX_REDIRECTED=1 "$DIR/../7.50.0-9030e49cbb/bin/sfdx" "$@"
```

Then I tried uninstalling it to install again. But on running the uninstall command `sfdx plugins:uninstall salesforcedx` , I am getting similar above error.

How do I start afresh to uninstall and install.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to uninstall the CLI , run the below in your MAC terminal one after the other

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/sfdx ~/.config/sfdx ~/.cache/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/sfdx
```

Please note this will also delete all the connections you would have authorized with the salesforce orgs. So you will have to reauthorize the org connections.